# Consulta a relación muchos a muchos, me devuelve valor null. Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Buenas tardes tengo una relación de User con Subjects. De  muchos a muchos, sabiendo que un usuario puede tener muchos subjects y un Subject muchos usuarios. tengo una tabla intermedia subject_user. Creo un seeder donde a cada usuario le asigno tres subjects, y el seeder funciona bien y me llena la tabla pero a la hora de hacer la consulta para traer los subjects asignados a ese user, me devuelve un valor nulo. Lo tengo de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo User

```
protected $guarded = ['id'],
public function subjects(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class);
}
```

Modelo Subject

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    
}
```

Tabla subject_user

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('subject_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('subject_id');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('subject_id')->references('id')->on('subjects')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Seeder que asigna 3 subjects a cada user

```
$users = User::all();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
       $user->subjects()->sync([
           rand(1, 5),
           rand(6, 10),
           rand(11, 14)
       ]);
      
    }
```

Este es mi controlador con el metodo show UserController

```
public function show(User $user){

    return view('users.show', compact('user'));
}
```

Mi vista

```
@dump($user->subjects)
```

Me devuelve un valor null, no entiendo porque.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si veo la tabla subject_user esta así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dd($user->subjects()) me retorna esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

lo que retorna `dd($user->subjects())` en si es el funcion belongtomany() , pero si haces `dd($user->subjects)` te mostrara una collection

[image: ejemplo de un shop con N product]

me gustaria saber que es lo que esta detras del codigo donde te sale null, en la vista.

Answer (score -1):

Para ese caso te recomiendo usar la relación "tiene muchos a través de":

```
public function subjects() 
{ 
    return $this->hasManyThrough(SubjectUser::class, Subject::class); 
}
```

Algo asi deberia la relación de tu modelo de usuarios.

Comment: Tengo dos modelos User y Subject. Es una relacion muchos a muchos. Segun la documentacion indica que debo crear una tabla intermedia que seria subject_user. Lo que me indicas es una relacion a travez de otro modelo. Mi problema radica en que en mi vista show cuando accedo a la relaciòn me indica que estoy accediendo a algo que no tiene nada. Pero pues como esta en los pantallazos la tabla subject_user esta llena. y todos los usuarios tienen asignado 3 subjects, estos fueron ingresados con un seeder, por lo que pienso que la relación funciona. pero obvio lago debe estar fallando.